# Removing &nbsp; with PHP after CURL request

Tags: php, html, curl

I get text from a website via CURL however it has   on the end on the original website, however when I return it back to mine, this is just a space(after looking at it in the source), however nothing seems to help even with str_replace, (string), strval() and so on.

Could anyone help?

Current code

```
    $country = $s->fetchBetween('<dt>Country:</dt><dd>','</dd>', $result);
    $country = strval($country);
    $country = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", strval($country));
    echo "start-{$country}-end";
    exit;
```

The value on the website that I'm "Curling" appears as

```
India&nbsp;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried `trim()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead.

```
$country = str_replace("&amp;nbsp;", "", strval($country));
```

Comment: ended up using $country = substr($country, 0, -1); however would still love to find out what on earth is going on here

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
$string = 'x&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;x ';
$pattern = '/&nbsp;/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```